# Java Pattern Class vs Database Like Operation which will be more efficent

Tags: java, mysql

Which is the most efficient way to retrieve data for performing search operation.

Following is the requirement application needs search like feature for known variables(search keywords).

NB:: Currently application already have search keywords stored in keys that are  stored in data cache in form of objects maintained at application level and are used for other purpose than performing search.

There are two possibilities now that are available to enable searching
(1) perform some pattern matching with java.util.regex.Pattern and then fetch the identified result rows from the cache or 
(2) Ask the database to perform the match and retrieve matching rows?

Need to know which is more efficient.

Any inputs on it or data on simulators performed for similar operation would be appreciated ?

Comment: So you're asking whether it is more efficient to (1) perform some pattern matching with `java.util.regex.Pattern` and then fetch the identified result rows from the cache or (2) ask the database to perform the match and retrieve matching rows?

Comment: Why tag the question 'guava'?

Comment: `Use singleton class` yeah, that fixes most problems in computer science ;)

Comment: @卢声远 Shengyuan Lu guava predicates uses pattern class a lot that come handy in such scenarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 is preferable because it does not involve network I/O.

Pattern matching and looking up in local cache will most likely take nanoseconds or a few milliseconds while sending a request to the database over the wire and waiting for the response will take a few dozen (or a few hundred) milliseconds. It's irrelevant that the database possibly implements the actual data look-up a bit faster than your own code.

Comment: Just as long as you can keep all the relevant search corpus stored in memory, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: @Marcel Stör Database also does indexing that Cache would not have it handy can that make difference

Comment: @AnandSanghvi correct, but network latency still is the major cost here

Comment: I tend to agree with you, but it really depends on the particular problem one is tackling. Keeping a concurrently-accesible, up-to-date, and size-bounded cache may not be worth the effort.

Comment: @Marcel Stör network latency can be minimal, if DB and App server are at same place will test results sometime soon and will post it for sure

Comment: @AnandSanghvi that's true, that's why I wrote "sending ... over the wire " ;-) when all is on the same machine it might even make a difference whether you address the database over the loopback nic (localhost/127.0.0.1) or over its "real" IP. It really boils down to a pre-mature optimization case. Also, the golden rule of performance optimization still applies: measure, tweak, measure again.

Answer (score 1):

This became too big to put into a comment:

To simply answer your question: Option 1 is preferable with what you describe, eg a local cache and a database accessible over network.

I'd like to emphasize "local" cache. If we're talking about a distributed cache you incur the network penalty and then the answer would be "we need more information". Factors to consider are the average size of a row, median network latency, read and write probability,... Answering this is a real pain.

When I face such a decision, I usually go through the following steps to decide what to use. The main metric here is simplicity, ie I'm looking for the most simple solution possible to save *my* time while still having a responsive site.

1. When starting, I try with no cache.
2. If that doesn't suffice and I still have one app server, I implement a local cache.
3. When I need to scale out by adding more app servers (behind a load-balancer), I try with no caches again (relying on the DB cache)
4. Only if that hits a performance limit, I implement a distributed cache system by attaching redis or memcache instances as needed (probably keeping a small cache on the individual app servers).

Comment: For more information, I would say there are multiple search options atleast 100 Sets each having more than 5000 rows.

Comment: Yeah, that's quite some variability. If you still have everything on the same server, try without a cache. If the cache is "closer" (in terms of network latency) to the frontend server, try the cache. But I can only repeat Marcel's advice: measure, tweak, measure again. Generally, try the solution with the least amount of software components. Complexity is what really kills.